# Question about Notation expected value $E_z(g(z_T))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am currently working through "The best choice problem for a random number of objects" by Presman and Sonin 1972 and in Theorem $2.1$ appears a Notation which is not explained there. The theorem says

"Suppose a Markov chain $(z_n,F_n,P_z)$, $n=1,2,\dots$ and a payoff function $g(z):0\leq g(z) \leq c$ are given. We put $A=\{z:g(z)\neq 0\}$ and define $a_1(w),\dots,a_k(w)$ as follows: $a_1(w)=1,a_k(w)=\min\{n:n>a_{k-1}(w), z_n \in A\}.$ Let $M'$ be the set of Markov times relative to the chain $z_n$ and put $Z_i=z_{a_i}$. We denote the set of Markov times relative to the chain $Z_i$ by $M$. Then for all $z$ $$\underset{T'\in M'}{\sup}\ E_zg(z_{T'})=\underset{T\in M}{\sup}\ E_zg(Z_T)".$$

My question is what does the $z$ in the index of $E_zg(Z_T)$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation with respect to z. It's basically telling you which variable to integrate over when performing the expectation.

In this case, I don't think it particularly adds clarity. But if there are multiple random variables, sometimes it may make clear with respect to which variable(s) to take the expectation.

Comment: So I can drop it without making the statement vague? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In this case, I think yes. But there's nothing wring with keeping it. It's more a stylistic thing.  Given that's from an "ancient" translation of an "ancient" Russian journal paper,  it may be stylistically different than current English language practice. In fact, Russian probability defines (or at least used to back in that era) cumulative distribution function to be left continuous, whereas most of the rest of the world uses right continuous.